# how to sort unordered images

Tags: c#, image, sorting

i am trying to sort unordered images into correct sequence. Here i am not getting the correct sequence. For this example i have chosen an object walk. Code is developed on c#.net. This is my code.

```
        for (i = 1; i <imagecount; i++)
        {
            fir = getDifference(image[i], image[i + 1]);

            for (j = i + 2; j <= imagecount; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                    j = j + 1;
                sec = getDifference(image[i], image[j]);
                if (fir > sec)
                {
                    fir = sec;
                    tmp = image[j];
                    image[j] = image[i + 1];
                    image[i+1] = tmp;
                    j = 0;
                }
```

I am following this approach. getDifference() method will give the difference between two images. Any simple logic on how to get sequenced images??

Comment: You should accept the correct answer to your questions. You can click the checkmark below the vote buttons to do this.

Comment: Can you post the code of getDifference()

Comment: 10 questions, no accepted answers is a bit selfish, don't you think?

Comment: @saurabh: getDifference() method will give the integer value as difference between two images. This method will analyze the changes of two images and will give the result. For ex: 1 2 3 4 5 is the correct sequence of images. getDifference(1,2) will be 90 where getDifference(1,3) will be 100, getDifference(1,4) will be 110 .. on so on. this code is in assembled. so v cant see it.

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to have a serious attempt at answering your question unless you accept answers to some of the questions you have already asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing about the getDifference() Method

Simple logic is OrderBy extesion method if using .net 3.5 or higher

or use Array.Sort() method in case of previous version.

Comment: based on the difference value we need to form the sequence. it is something like bubble sort. bur here we are dealing with a value which is derived from two images.